# How to call another form using a panel in the main form?

Tags: forms, delphi

I am coding in Delphi 10. I have two forms: `FormPrincipal`, which is the main form, and `Formbanco` the one I want to call.

In `FormPrincipal` I put a panel `PanelCorpo` and I want to call `Formbanco` and show it in the position of this panel.

I have tried two methods, but both did not work. See below:

#### 1st)  `FormPrincpal` calling `Formbanco` using `Showmodal`:

```
// TActionlist  OnExecute event 

procedure TFormPrincipal.AbreFormBancoExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  try         
    Application.CreateForm(Tformbanco,Formbanco);
    Formbanco.Parent := PanelCorpo;
    Formbanco.Align  := alclient;
    Formbanco.Showmodal;
  finally
    Freeandnil(formbanco);         
  end;
end;
```

The behavior was: it opened the called form `Formbanco` properly, but frozen. Both forms did not allow to focus!

#### 2nd) FormPrincpal calling Formbanco using `Show`:

```
// TActionlist  OnExecute event 

procedure TFormPrincipal.AbreFormBancoExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  try
    Application.CreateForm(Tformbanco,Formbanco);
    Formbanco.Parent := PanelCorpo;
    Formbanco.Align  := alclient;
    Formbanco.Show;
  finally
    Freeandnil(formbanco);         
  end;
end;
```

The behaviour was: it blinks very quickly the `Formbanco`, almost not visible,  and continues in `FormPrincipal`. I can't access `Formbanco`!

I do appreciate help on this.

Comment: FWIW, there is no such thing as XE10.

Comment: _In the FormPrincipal I put a Tpanel "PanelCorpo" and I want to call Formbanco and show it in the **position** of this panel_ is really confusing. is the form supposed to show in the position of the panel or inside the panel?

Comment: Nasreddine, you are right,  the Formbanco should appear inside the panel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A modal form can't be a child. So the second attempt using `Show` is better. The mistake there is to destroy the form. Remember that `Show` is asynchronous, so you destroy the form as soon as you create it. Don't do that. You will need to destroy it somewhere else, in response to another event. You will know what that should be.

The function should look like this:

```
procedure TFormPrincipal.AbreFormBancoExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin   
  Formbanco := Tformbanco.Create(Self);
  Formbanco.Parent := PanelCorpo;
  Formbanco.Align := alclient;
  Formbanco.BorderIcons := [];
  Formbanco.BorderStyle := bsNone;
  Formbanco.Show;
end;
```

Comment: _In the FormPrincipal I put a Tpanel "PanelCorpo" and I want to call Formbanco and show it in the **position** of this panel_ is really confusing. is the form supposed to show in the position of the panel or inside the panel?

Comment: That the code sets the form Parent property makes the intent clear.

Comment: David ,  thanks. Your code make it work as I expected.

Comment: I still have some other issues to solve in order to get the full menu functionality by calling other forms perfectly.  
My intention is to have the FormPrincipal as the opening form and the  holder of main menu. 
1) How to call each form (form2,form3,form4, ...) using the Tmenu located in the FormPrincipal while keeping the FormPrincipal and menu visilbe ?  
2) How to close a called form currently visible  as soon as another form is called from the menu item ? 
3) Is this the right approach manage  forms modules ?

Comment: I think I answered the question that you asked. Don't try to get us to do the rest of your architecture design in comments, with only a limited understanding of your goals.

Comment: David,let me be more specific : I'll have several forms being called, so I'll need to close current opened the FormPrincipal  before to call another form.    procedure TFormPrincipal.AbreFormBancoExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin   
  //(1) -- Identify which for is opened in the FormPrincipal   ???
  //(2) -- Close this form before to call the another one with the below  ??code   
  Formbanco := Tformbanco.Create(Self);
  Formbanco.Parent := PanelCorpo;
  Formbanco.Align := alclient;
  Formbanco.BorderIcons := [];
  Formbanco.BorderStyle := bsNone;
  Formbanco.Show;
end;   Thanks !

Comment: I answered the question you asked. It's at the top of the page. You can't ask new questions in a comment.

Comment: David , something is stil strange.  Although I can see the called forms, when I enter into it I can not edit or iput date in grid or fields ?  What is wrong with this calling ?

Comment: I see you've asked a new question as I suggested. Now, what about this question. If you feel the question that was first asked has been answered, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score -1):

If you use TForm as a panel, don't do it. Create TFrame and include it as every component on your FormPrincipal.

If you want to include the content of a form on an other (inside a panel, a tabcontrol, ...) you can only do if you put a tpanel (or tlayer) as top level parent on the second form. When you want to include it on an other form change it's Parent property (and it's alignment if necessary). You don't have to show your second form in this case (but of course create it) : the panel/layout is on first one and showed on it.

Comment: Patrick, thanks for the remarks.   I'm sorry but I did not undertand it completely.  Could you include a example of code ?   Please havin in mind that I want the FormPrincipal be the opening form of the application and from that I want to call several other forms, one at once, through a menu located in this FormPrincipal.   I do appreciate your help.  Thanks.

Comment: I second this. David's answer is correct, but by what you described I'd also suggest, as Patrick, thant you start using nested TFrames instead of TForms.